# What is the best way/UX to handle logic show item's detail from ListView/RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, user-experience

I am working on a simple app with only two activity.

- The first activity(named as StudentListActivity) have a recyclerview show the list of student. Each item is a student and list student data will get from server.
- The second activity(named as StudentDetailActivity) is detail of specific student and be started when click on recyclerview's item in StudentListActivity.

And what I confuse is the way to get student detail data. I consider in two ways:

1. When click on recyclerview's item in StudentListActivity, I will pass entire student object to StudentDetailActivity and show it regularly. This way will fast and alway available but come wrong in case of the student no longer exist but still show detail on StudentDetailActivity.
2. I just pass only the student's id and call api to server in oder to get student info depend on that id. This way can avoid the case in the first way because we call to the server and ensure the student is existed on database. But it take time to call api, let user waiting for and maybe affect to user experience.

Any one tell me what is the best way/UX for that situation, or are there still other solutions. Suggest me, please!

Thanks,

Comment: Your second option is more efficient as this will also be beneficial for activity 1. In my opinion its beneficial to only download the data that you are going to display because imagine if you are dealing with thousands of records. Then on second activity, just do another API call as you've stated

Comment: Thanks for give your opinion, it will be really helpful for me. Honestly, I have no idea about this situation, so I need to hear more suggestions from the others before decide to use which way.

Comment: Insteag of creating second activity use [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to show details. Its more efficient than activity. Activity takes time to create itself. Choose Option 1 is better way to load data faster. Everytime in activity 1 load data from server to avoid non existing users data present in recylerview.

Comment: Your most welcome mate. Another thing I would suggest you to consider if you want to design your application like email apps (downloads emails when internet is available and cache emails for offline use)

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH: You are right that use fragments(I call it StudentDetailFragment) to show detail will make data load faster. But can you tell more clearly how to design the StudentListActivity(with listview fill entire the screen)  + StudentDetailFragment(associate with StudentListActivity). Do them stack each other ? And using show/hide logic to switch between the activity and fragment ?  
Thanks

Comment: @Nero: Yeah, you are right. Caching can solve problem, don't let user waiting for on the second load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## From an UX perspective, I would do the following:

Let's say in your RecyclerView, each item consists of a name, and image. When you navigate over to a detail activity for a specific student, I would pass on (along the id) the name and the image URL to the other activity and implement [Activity Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions). Something along the lines of:

[image]
*[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions)*

And from then on, I would use the id to retrieve the rest of the information. I would advise against sending large data over intents, as they were not designed for that purpose. Also if you make your Activity to depend on an object instead of an ID to start, you will have a hard time enable direct app linking and allowing users to share pages from your app. Also consider the Activity lifecycle, and what happens on configuration change. See more [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/the-android-lifecycle-cheat-sheet-part-i-single-activities-e49fd3d202ab), and see the following diagram:

[image]
*[Source](https://github.com/JoseAlcerreca/android-lifecycles/blob/master/cheatsheetactivities.pdf)*

## From an architectural perspective, I would suggest the following:

Implement a local database, and ensure your network requests are cached properly. This will enable you more speedier results and an offline-ready application. Between your UI and data sources, implement a Repository pattern, along the lines of:

[image]
*[Source](https://medium.com/corebuild-software/android-repository-pattern-using-rx-room-bac6c65d7385)*

Comment: Yes ! I got your idea. You explain it so clearly. Almost things I feel it's appropriate to this situation. Just only about "Also consider the Activity lifecycle, and what happens on configuration change". I have read the article you send, but I don't see any relation between "Activity lifecycle" and "start activity with and object/id". I think whatever using object or id to start activity, it will walk through the same lifecycle. Can you explain more detail ?

Comment: @TruongGiangDam It was more in line of your suggestion with passing on whole objects into the activity. If you do so, and the user rotates/changes configuration, you would need to ensure you can serialize that object and save it with the instance state. Only having id/title can makes this easier - that was the reason why I suggested you read that article to remember it when making activities/fragments start with heavy intents.

Comment: Yeah, you mean the cost to save data when configuration change between heavy object and id/title. Thanks so much. Now I understood :)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the application which i developed comes across this situation. What I always prefer to do is when user land on to student detail activity, load from cache if available and parallely trigger a Web service call. Once the server response available update the student details activity with latest info and store the same in cache. This way transition will be very smooth,  and user won't feel waiting...

Comment: Thanks so much, I have no idea in this situation, so I decided to believe in your experience, specially about caching, I never think about it before.